# Moving mobile sync to home laptop

Tags: ipad, ipod-touch, backup

My iPod Touch is synced to my work Mac. My iPad is synced to my home laptop. I want to move the Touch sync/backup to the laptop. If I copy the latest Touch Mobile Sync backup to the laptop will it clash/interfere with the iPad backup? I don't care about music just apps and preferences. I realize they're different numbers in the file name but is that enough to distinguish them?

Answer (score 1):

You can back up as many iDevices to your computer as you please (technically). On my computer, I sync and have backed up at least three different iDevices.

All you need to do, is plug in your iPod Touch to your laptop, open iTunes, and back it up. It will know the difference between your iPod touch and iPad.

The difference comes in if you sync music from a computer (but that isn't relavent to this question, so I won't elaborate).